# What is to stop a user running code one behalf of the website in a browser?

Tags: http, browser

I am having trouble understanding how browsers stop origin spoofing because surely if you have access to the browser you can make it run code as if it was on a website. This would allow it to make requests that are only allowed from a certain origin which would be a huge security risk.

For example, would it not be easy enough to just edit the cache for a sites js and then the browser would just run it. Even if there was some kind of check to ensure the code was original and not modified, it wouldn't be that hard to simply remove that part from the browser.

Thanks for trying to help me in advance!